# Exception while sending email

Tags: c#

Error:

> System.Mail.SmtpException: System.IO.IOEXCEPTION
>   {"Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."}

Code:

```
string mailServer = "outlook.domain.com";

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(mailServer, 587);
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

var AuthenticationDetails = new NetworkCredential("user@domain.com", "password");
client.Credentials = AuthenticationDetails;

using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage("user@domain.com", recipient))
{
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    message.Body = htmlString;
    message.Subject = "Test Email";

    client.Send(message);
}
```

Comment: Read the exception: "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.". Try reading this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187005%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Update the client computer to the server version of the SQL Server Native Client.

Comment: "Unable to read data" sounds like specifying the Encoding can help. Try 'mail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by providing the correct Host name and Port. Thank you all for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have the wrong server-adress. Take a look here:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/outlook/send-receive-from-app

Use the correct adress for your use.

```
string mailServer = "smtp-mail.outlook.com";

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(mailServer, 25); // or 587
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

var AuthenticationDetails = new NetworkCredential("user@domain.com", "password");
client.Credentials = AuthenticationDetails;

using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage("user@domain.com", recipient))
{
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    message.Body = htmlString;
    message.Subject = "Test Email";

    client.Send(message);
}
```

Tips from this question:

[Cant emails through exchange: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161253/cant-emails-through-exchange-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the)

Comment: Tried this getting error - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: @ShankarAnumula Do you have port 25 open? You can try with port 587

Comment: @ShankarAnumula
Hmm... I can't find any other mistakes. Have you tried turning off your firewall? I see others have had the same issue as you. Someone said it was blocked by their antivirus.

Also, you may try this mailServer: "smtp.office365.com" with port 587

Comment: Fixed this, issue is with host name, I worked with my service desk team to get the correct host name. Thanks for helping me to sort this out